Cancelling downloaded update already scheduled for installation
Just a simple question: how do I cancel an update that was downloaded from being installed? Is it possible to skip just a specific update? (if it's not an optional update) Or does window treat all "major" updates as mandatory and prerequisites for later updates?
I'm not entirely sure yet but I think a specific update is causing issues with my Windows 11. Not really wanting to reinstall windows 11 right now..

Under Check for Updates does it show as optional or required?

Do you mean "cancel" or do you mean "uninstall" or "remove"? If you believe the update is causing issues, that usually means you believe it is already installed, so "canceling" probably isn't what you're actually looking for. Have you done any research regarding uninstalling already-installed patches, or preventing a specific patch from installing?

I meant literally what is written in the post.. cancelling a downloaded update that is pending installation.
